# Arduino Pro Micro as "keyboard" on a PC - prints on the PC "=" instead of "-" HID-library

Tags: windows, arduino, symbols, arduino-uno

i uploaded the code to Arduino pro micro. But the "-" symbol is printing like "=" symbol. Please help, idk what to do...

```
 Keyboard.print("iexplore -k google.com");
```

[image]

UPDATE:
I'm using "HID-projects" libary
Arduino leonardno / pro micro is simulating keyboard on Windows 10 LAPTOP. Something like rubber ducky just Arduino version.
If I'm using  "keyboard.h" libary, it do the same problem

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <HID-Project.h>
#include <HID-Settings.h>

// Utility function
void typeKey(int key){
  Keyboard.press(key);
  delay(500);
  Keyboard.release(key);
}

void setup()
{
  // Start Keyboard and Mouse
  AbsoluteMouse.begin();
  Keyboard.begin();

  // Start Payload
  delay(400);

  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  Keyboard.press(114);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();

  delay(400);

  Keyboard.print("iexplore -k google.com");

  delay(400);

  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);

  // End Payload

  // Stop Keyboard and Mouse
  Keyboard.end();
  AbsoluteMouse.end();
}

// Unused
void loop() {}
```

Comment: What libraries are you using? Where is the complete function for transfering the code to the window. Is the micro emulating a keyboard and if yes on which device. To solve a problem we need infos . Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: So sorry... now its edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HID Project (as keyboard.h) only support US_ENGLISH - so your OS has to be set to this layout. The "-" vs "=" is most likly a different keyboard layout. Try

```
Keyboard.print("iexplore ")-
Keyboard.press(KEY_MINUS);
Keyboard.print("k google.com");
```

if its again "=" you have a keyboard layout problem in your OS.As a test for this problem try the following

```
Keyboard.print("Layout test _-*$%&/()!?#;,:...");
```

If different letters are print its the OS keyboard layout